# synced folder in Vagrant: The host path of the shared folder is missing

Tags: vagrant

I'm starting a vm with Vagrant, when I want to shared a folder the message: `The host path of the shared folder is missing: vagrant_getting_started/`
appears

Here are the details of the vm (the provider is virtualbox), in the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    config.vm.box_version = "1.1.0"
    config.vm.synced_folder "vagrant_getting_started/", "/home/jesi/vagrant/vagrant_getting_started"
```

the operating system is Ubuntu. how do I solve it? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the source folder on the host machine so you need to have this folder accessible either with an absolute path or with a relative path to your Vagrantfile or as the [ducumentation says](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html):

> relative to the project root

Either way the source directory must exist, while the target one will be created by vagrant on the guest.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for answering. the host machine is the one with ubuntu the path is /home/jesi/vagrant/grant >> so this is the folder that was created when i started vagrant as the first virtual machine and I should put this path in the first "" part? like this >> "/home/jesi/vagrant/grant", what do i put in the second part ""? what's the meaning of "an absolute path of where to share the folder within the guest machine"? do you have a Vagrantfile as an example?

Thank you